# Does BMC Remedy expose REST APIs

Tags: remedy

I want to integrate BMC Remedy with some other tool. So I am thinking of calling curl command to fetch some change request status from Remedy. Does BMC Remedy expose REST APIs ? How can we call them using curl ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BMC has a Load of webservices as a default. You can read more on their documentation site regarding how they are exposed:

https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ars81/Web+service+standards

They are exposed as WDSL. You can ask your Remedy Admins to provide a list with the URLs etc. If you are running the ITSM suite, there are several ootb webservices, but depending on your needs, you may need to have some custom ones created...

Note that this is not an answer that fits all versions of Remedy. newer versions may expose REST APIs. As is stated in other answers, as of version 9.0, yes BMC exposes REST API. Both for ARS and CMDB. More info [here](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ac9000/REST+API).

Answer (score 2):

AS of version 9.0, yes BMC exposes REST API. Both for ARS and CMDB.
More info [here](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ac9000/REST+API).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not on version 9.0 yet, we have had a lot of success using ARAPI Community edition by VIPCON.  It is basically a Java app that listens for HTTP requests and translates them into AR System API calls on the backend.  The community edition is FREE but there is no support provided (which is more than fair).

Here is their introductory post to BMC Communities:
https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-29073

And their GitHub page for the latest release: https://github.com/manyosit/arapi